Is there a ring $\Lambda$ such that $\text{Id}_{\Lambda}(\Lambda) < \text{FID}(\Lambda)$?
In the article INJECTIVE DIMENSION IN NOETHERIAN RINGS, Proposition 4.2 states:
Proposition 4.2. Suppose $\Lambda$ is left Noetherian. If $\text{Id}_{\Lambda}(\Lambda)$ and left $\text{FID}(\Lambda)$ are both finite, they are equal.
I can find a ring $\Lambda$ such that $$\text{Id}_{\Lambda}(\Lambda) > \text{FID}(\Lambda),$$ and the example is easy to find. However, I have not been able to find a ring $\Lambda$ such that $$\text{Id}_{\Lambda}(\Lambda) < \text{FID}(\Lambda)$$ so far.
This raises the question: Is there a ring $\Lambda$ such that $$\text{Id}_{\Lambda}(\Lambda) < \text{FID}(\Lambda)?$$

So, essentially, you want a ring of finite injective dimension admitting modules of arbitrarily large, finite injective dimension, correct?

(That should be impossible by the same argument as in the proof of the cited proposition. Unless you're talking non-noetherian, then no idea.)

Yes, you are right. When $\Lambda$ is left Noetherian and $Id_{\Lambda}(\Lambda) < FID(\Lambda)$, then $FID(\Lambda)$ must be $\infty$.

@Ben Thank you. From the proof of Proposition 4.2 in the article INJECTIVE DIMENSION IN NOETHERIAN RINGS, it does not seem to imply that there is no left Noetherian ring for which $Id_{\Lambda}(\Lambda) < FID(\Lambda)$.

To me, the proof seems to imply that if $\Lambda$ is left-noetherian and of finite injective dimension, then for every $\Lambda$-module $A$ of finite injective dimension, $\mathop{Id}\Lambda(A)\leq \mathop{Id}\Lambda(\Lambda)$. But perhaps I wasn't reading carefully, I apologise for any confusion.

Ah, I do see my mistake now, sorry, you're right.
